# Applying OLS regression on model with binary dependent variable to run diagnostic tests

Tags: logistic, least-squares, stata, binary-data, probit

My dependent variable is binary and am therefore using a logit regression but since the diagnostic tests to run for logit are different can I not just regress the variables with OLS and run the standard tests to check if is BLUE.

Comment: Short answer is no. Might be good to take a step back and explain how would you interpret ols regression on binary data. One unit increase in X gives me extra 0.3 patients alive?

Comment: Do a search for LPM (Linear Probability Model).